# 'Date': 'class' type redefinition: ERROR (calendar.cpp file error)

Tags: c++

This is my Calendar.cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "Calendar.h"

char months[12][10] = { "January", "February", "March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December" };
```

the problem is showing it in the class declaration.

```
class Date {

private:
int dd, mm, yy;
public:

Date() {
    dd = 1; mm = 1; yy = 1900;
}

Date(int m, int d, int y) {

    dd = d; mm = m; yy = y;
    bool check = checkdate();
    if (!check) {
        cout << "Invalid date give. Resetting to default" << endl;
        dd = mm = 1; yy = 1900;
    }
}

bool checkdate() {
    bool leap = checkleapyear();
    if (mm>12 || mm <= 0) //check months
        return false;

    if ((mm == 1 || mm == 3 || mm == 5 || mm == 7 || mm == 8 || mm == 10 || mm == 12) && dd>31)
        return false;
    else if (leap && mm == 2 && dd>29)
        return false;
    else if (mm == 2 && dd>28)
        return false;
    else if (dd>30)
        return false;
    return true;
}

bool checkleapyear() {
    if ((yy % 400 == 0) || (yy % 4 == 0 && yy % 100 != 0))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
string toString() {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << months[mm - 1] << " " << dd << "," << yy;
    return ss.str();
}
Date nextDate() {
    int y, d, m;

    if (mm == 2) {
        bool flag = checkleapyear();
        if (flag) {
            if (dd >= 29) {
                d = 1;
                m = 3;
            }
            else
                d++;
        }
        else {
            if (dd >= 28) { d = 1; m = 3; }
            else
                d++;
        }
        y = yy;
        return Date(m, d, y);
    }

    if ((mm == 1 || mm == 3 || mm == 5 || mm == 7 || mm == 8 || mm == 10) && dd>31)
    {
        m++;
        d = 1;
        y = yy;
    }
    else if (mm == 12) { m = 1; y = yy++; d = 1; }
    else if (dd>30) {
        m++;
        d = 1;
        y = yy;
    }
    else {
        d = dd + 1;
        m = mm;
        y = yy;
    }

    return Date(m, d, y);

}

void compareDates(Date &d)
{
    if (d.yy>this->yy)
        cout << "The first date comes before the second date" << endl;
    else if (d.yy<this->yy)
        cout << "The second date comes before the first date" << endl;
    else if (d.yy == this->yy) {
        if (d.mm>this->mm)
            cout << "The first date comes before the second date" << endl;
        else if (d.mm<this->mm)
            cout << "The second date comes before the first date" << endl;
        else {

            if (d.dd>this->dd)
                cout << "The first date comes before the second date" << endl;
            else if (d.dd<this->dd)
                cout << "The second date comes before the first date" << endl;
            else {
                cout << "The two dates are equal" << endl;
            }
        }

    }
}

};
```

This is my Calendar.h file.

```
#ifndef CALENDAR_H
#define CALENDAR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Date {
private:
    int dd, mm, yy;
public:
    Date();
    Date(int m, int d, int y);
    bool checkdate();
    bool checkleapyear();
    string toString();
    Date nextDate();
    void compareDates(Date &d);
};
#endif
```

I get an error in my Calendar.cpp file saying - '"Date': 'class' type redefinition". I have tried to change a few things inside the class to make it work but it seems that there is some other problem.

Comment: Why do you have two `class Date` definitions?  How are classes and their implementations described in the C++ book you're using?  The compiler is literally telling you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have declaration of your class in the Calender.h file, your implementation in the Calender.cpp is in fact redfining your class. The correct way to do that would be to reference the class using the scope resolution operator ' **::** '

Your Calender.cpp file should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "Calendar.h"

char months[12][10] = { "January", "February", "March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December" };

// your default no-args class constructor
Date::Date(){
    dd = 1; mm = 1; yy = 1900;
}

/*
        Another Way you could implement your constructor is by using initialisation lists (check our the second link in my answer to know more)
        Date::Date(int m, int d, int y) : mm(m), dd(d), yy(y) { }
*/

Date::Date(int m, int d, int y) {
    // your constructor code here
}

bool Date::checkdate(){
    // your implementation here
}
bool Date::checkleapyear(){
    // your implementation here
}
string Date::toString(){
    // your implementation here
}
Date Date::nextDate(){
    // your implementation here
}
void Date::compareDates(Date &d){
    // your implementation here
}
```

That's it. It really helps in having your class declaration and implementation separate.

Check out these links below to help you better understand:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/89-class-code-and-header-files/

http://www.cppforschool.com/tutorial/separate-header-and-implementation-files.html

Comment: please mark this as the answer if it solves your problem